# setfib() not support in FREEBSD amd64

Tags: x86-64, system-calls, freebsd

Setfib() syscall does not support in FREEBSD amd64 and its return Function not implemented error

https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=setfib&sektion=2

Comment: Probably the best place to report a possible bug is here: https://www.freebsd.org/support/bugreports.html

Comment: what version of FreeBSD do you use?